# onLocationChange() is not called...using FuseLocationApi ...checked all the solutions tried all of them ....but still nothing worked

Tags: java, android, api, firebase, dictionary

For checking purposes I have inserted `log` in every method there in the code. onConnected() method is called but it doesn't go further to OnLocationChanged()

**DriverMapActivity**

```
public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Button save;
GoogleApiClient mgooogleapiclient;
Location mlastlocation;
LocationRequest mlocationRequest;
Marker marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    //  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Log.d("conn","api got");

    }
    else
    {
        checkLocationPermission();
        Log.d("conn","api gotout");
    }
    Log.d("conn","api gotout");



}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mgooogleapiclient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mgooogleapiclient.connect();
    Log.d("buildapi","api co");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    mlocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mlocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mlocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mlocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mgooogleapiclient, mlocationRequest, this);
    }
    Log.d("conn","in on vconnected");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 mlastlocation=location;
 LatLng latLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
 Log.d("see location","lati:  "+location.getLatitude()+"   longi:"+location.getLongitude());
 MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions();
 markerOptions.position(latLng);
 markerOptions.title("Current position");
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
 if(marker!=null)
 {
     marker.remove();
 }
 marker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");
    GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(ref);
    geoFire.setLocation("DriverId",new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");
    GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(ref);
    geoFire.removeLocation("DriverId");
}
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DriverMapActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            Log.d("conn","in dialog box");
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mgooogleapiclient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mgooogleapiclient, mlocationRequest, this);
                }

            } else {


                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }


    }
}
}
```

**Android Manifest File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DriverMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_driver_map">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**build Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.vypodriver"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Here I am trying to get the driver location every second and want to update it to firebase  But onLocationChange is not called anything is done. Tried to run it on android phone running on Noghut **

Comment: Are you sure that `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` is being called? I think that you don't have the location permission once you reach that line

Comment: Enabling location on mobile prior to installing and i have also code for its proper checking and again wrote this statement LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates again at onRequestPermsionResult() method

Comment: Need to do anything else?

Comment: It's always possible that the device can't find its location. Network based location may require a SIM card and GPS based position may require going outdoors or at least close to a window.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the method `requestLocationUpdates` is not being called because you don't have location permissions.

Add an else here:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mgooogleapiclient, mlocationRequest, this);
} else {
    checkLocationPermission(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake, which I assume is typo.

In `onMapReady()` you're checking the permission status in the following way:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

However, in the `onConnected()` method your condition is the following:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Notice that the second condition requires `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to be false and the first condition requires it to be true.